# What does a second equals = within vba variable assignment do?

Tags: excel, vba, boolean-expression

Perplexed by the function of using a second = sign in vba. eg. s = Int(xVal) + (xVal = n + 1)

I had been deciphering some code and came across the following line which is perplexing me somewhat and despite some extensive research and debugging I seem to be struggling to find the answer:

```vb
s = Int(xVal) + (xVal = n + 1)
```

and

```vb
p(i, 3) = A(i)(s + 3 + (s = n)) + (s = n) * (p(i, 1) - p(i, 2))
```

My question is what is the function of the comparisons within the parentheses after the first assignment = sign?

TIA

Comment: I believe these are treated as `Boolean` values ( `True` or `False`). I believe `True` is -1 while `False` is 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(s = n)
```

If both s and n have the same value then this evaluates to `True`, which can be coerced to its underlying value of -1 by other arithmetic operations.

Eg:

```
? True * 1   '>> -1
? False * 1   '>> 0
```

So this:

```
s = Int(xVal) + (xVal = n + 1)
```

is like writing:

```
If xVal = n + 1 Then
    s = Int(xVal) + -1
else
    s = Int(xVal) + 0
end if
```

or:

```
s = Int(xVal) + IIf(xVal = n + 1, -1, 0)
```